# Need a Regex to get select name

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a variable which stores some string.

```
eg var string = '<select mltiple="" name="multi_select_frV6Yzed4dxzsotOvJ5cXg9Aa[]" aria-required="true">';
```

i want to get multi_select_frV6Yzed4dxzsotOvJ5cXg9Aa[] using regex expression. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is unclear and unformatted

Comment: Why do you need a regexp? Can't you parse the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way as well (not using any regex here)

```
var string = '<select mltiple="" name="multi_select_frV6Yzed4dxzsotOvJ5cXg9Aa[]" aria-required="true">';

console.log($($.parseHTML(string)).attr("name")); //gives 'multi_select_frV6Yzed4dxzsotOvJ5cXg9Aa[]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to retrieve that value:

```
var matches = /name="(.*)"\s/gi.exec(string);
console.log(matches[1]); // = "multi_select_frV6Yzed4dxzsotOvJ5cXg9Aa[]"
```

You would obviously need to make the code more robust to deal with cases where the attribute is not found.

You could also use jQuery:

```
console.log($(string).attr('name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

See **[this](https://regex101.com/r/fE4qT0/1)** working `regex`.

Here is the javascript code.

```js
var re = /name="([^"]*)/g;
var str = '<select mltiple="" name="multi_select_frV6Yzed4dxzsotOvJ5cXg9Aa[]" aria-required="true">';
var m;

m = re.exec(str);

alert(m[1]);
```